# Using a function on change in Kendo UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I create a datepicker and ask to launch an alert on change :

```
    <input id="datepicker" />
<script>
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    change: function() {
    var value = this.value();
    alert(value); //value is the selected date in the datepicker
    }
    });

</script>
```

No problem with this, it's working.
Now I try to make a function that take the value of the datepicker, and display it on an alert :

```
function Test(){
var toto = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
var value = toto.value();
alert(value);
}
```

And modify the the datepicker like this :

```
<input id="datepicker" />
<script>
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    change: Test()
    });
</script>
```

And it's not working anymore. The "Test" method is launched without changes on the datepicker, and the datepicker now look like this :
[datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Uff.png)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last part to this:

```
<input id="datepicker" />
<script>
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    change: Test
    });
</script>
```

You were setting the change event to return value of the `Test()` function